# Java call method on a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, minecraft

I'm making a Minecraft 1.8 client, and I'm trying to create a loading screen animation.

I know that updating the screen every time Minecraft loads something would make the animation choppy, so I tried making it run asynchronously, updating the screen every 10 milliseconds. The following code runs in Minecraft.java when the game starts:

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    int xPosition = // calculation of the value
    // draw the rectangle
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10L);
    }
    catch (InterruptexException ignored) {
    
    }
    this.updateDisplay(); // render the rectangle
});
```

However, due to CompletableFuture running the code in a different thread, LWJGL can't find the rendering context (it can be found in the Minecraft thread), and can't update the screen (an IllegalStateException is thrown).

Is it possible to call the **updateDisplay** (or any) method on a **different** thread instead of the current thread?

Comment: Create a queue of tasks which is processed from the UI thread. Then add your display update task to that queue from the other thread. That way you can add all sorts of different tasks to the queue from other threads to be executed by the main thread.

Comment: How would I do that?
Do I create a list of runnables, run them 1 by 1, and when one is finished update the display?